# Solutions to a cubic via intersection of a parabola and hyberbola

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

This is regarding Omar Khayyam's geometric solution to the cubic.

Assume we intersect a parabola of the form

$$yc=x^{2}$$

and a hyperbola

$$y^{2}=x(x-h)$$

where $c^{2}=a$ and $c^{2}h=b$. How is the first coordinate of the points of intersection (in the first quadrant) a solution to

$$x^{3}+b=ax$$

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

We want to intersect:
$$y=\dfrac{x^2}{c}\implies y^2=\dfrac{x^4}{c^2}$$
$$y^2=x(x-h)$$
So:
$$\dfrac{x^4}{c^2}=x(x-h)$$
$$\dfrac{x^3}{c^2}=x-h$$
$$x^3=c^2x-hc^2$$
using definitions of $a$ and $b$:
$$x^3+b=ax$$

The first quadrant thing isn't always true (take a negative $c$, for instance)