# Omar Khayyam's method of solving cubics compared to 16th century Italian

Tags: math-history, cubics

Just wondering if anyone can clarify these two ways of solving cubics. Theres not many examples online which I can find.

> Q1. Give Omar Khayyam’s geometrical solution to the cubic equation
>   $x^3 + 64x = 384.$
>   Check that the geometric solution is correct using modern methods.
>
> Q2. Then Using the formula established by the 16th-century Italian method, find a solution to
>   the cubic equation $ x^3 + 63x = 316.$

For Q1 I know that we transform this into finding the intersection of a parabola and a hyperbola, however I'm having difficulty applying this formula to an actual example.

I'd appreciate any guidance or examples which can be given

Comment: I believe the first method has something to do with finding the intersection of a parabola and a hyperbola. For instance, see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986321/solutions-to-a-cubic-via-intersection-of-a-parabola-and-hyberbola/1986330#1986330

Comment: Sorry @Mastrem I should have included that in my question. I can find plenty of explanations like the one you have linked but applying it to an actual question has me confused.

Comment: "Check that the geometric solution is correct using modern methods." Not clear what it is supposed to be. The simplest test is the substitution into the original equation, but it is not very modern. Numerical methods? Newton's method or dichotomous search are pretty old too.

Answer (score 0):

First: Omar Khayyam's method. Let's solve:
$$x^3+64x=384$$
We need to turn our equation into something of the form:
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{c}\right)^2=x(d-x)$$
With $c$ and $d$ constants. Then we can find the intersection of:
$$y^2=x(d-x)$$
$$y=\frac1cx^2$$
The $x$-coordinate of the intersection will be a solution to our equation. Ok, so let's do it:
\begin{align}
x^3+64x&=384\\
x^3&=384-64x\\
\frac{x^3}{64}&=6-x\\
\frac{x^4}{64}&=x(6-x)\\
\left(\frac{x^2}{8}\right)^2&=x(6-x)
\end{align}
So, we need to find the intersection of:
$$y=\frac18x^2$$
and:
$$y^2=x(6-x)$$

Now for Cardano's (The Italian Mathematician) Formula. We have:
$$x^3+63x=316$$
$$x^3+63x-316=0$$
Cardano's formula tells us that the equation:
$$x^3+px+q$$ 
has the solutions:
$$x=\sqrt[3]{-\frac q2+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac q2-\sqrt{\frac{q^2}4+\frac{p^3}{27}}}$$
So filling it all in gives:
$$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac {316}2+\sqrt{\frac{316^2}4+\frac{63^3}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac {316}2-\sqrt{\frac{316^2}4+\frac{63^3}{27}}}$$

Comment: The equation $y^2=x(6-x)$ describes a circle, not a hyperbola.

Comment: @Did O, of course, that is because we take $6-x$. If it would be $6+x$ it would be a hyperbola.

Comment: Parabola and hyperbola would be $$\left(\frac{x}{8}\right)^2+1=\frac{6}{x}$$.